# save image when using php shell_exec and mac osx terminal command screen capture?

Tags: php, macos, shell, terminal

I was experimenting with shell_exec and commands, and I can't seem to get this work. Im using the php shell_exec() function and running a screen capture command to take a snapshot of the desktop. When running the script locally through coda, it works fine. Then i ran it through my installion of apache through htdocs, and it runs, yet it doesn't save the image anywhere? For browsers, do i need to change the directory at all? this is what my super simple script looks like. Is this even possible?

```
   <?
   $command = "screencapture -iWP ~/Random/test.png";
   shell_exec($command);
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't currently have access to a Mac to test, but I'd be extremely surprised and more than a little concerned if that did work.

**On the server**, apache should be running under a different user ID to the logged in user, which means the attempt to grab the framebuffer should fail.

If it did at least write (or try to write) an image, then it will be ~/Random/test.png; e.g. if apache runs as a user called apache, the target filename is ~apache/Random/test.png

OSX is basically UNIX, and a key feature of UNIX-like operating systems is security. The video framebuffer should only be accessible to processes running under the UID of the logged in user (or root). Daemon processes like apache httpd should be running under their own, non-root UID.

Comment: obviously this would be a huuuuge security issue if it worked on the users end, but the command still runs, so i have no idea where its saving the file (if it even is). Im using the XAAMP installation of apache, so the root localhost folder is in htdocs, but still notice. If I had a mac server running, however, could this actually work? It would screenshot the server's screen, not the users, right?

Comment: I'll edit my answer; on the server, httpd and the desktop session should be different UIDs.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to specify the full path of the executable. Also, specifying the full path of the output PNG would help too because they're different users.

Run the command

```
which screencapture
```

To find the path that the executable is located in. The output file must be in a writable directory for the user that apache is running under (usually apache). You can check the user that apache is running under by looking in the apache configuration, or just running "top" (as root).

Hope that helps.

Comment: sorry I'm a bit of a noob, i opened up the config file, where in it can i find the user?

Comment: every distribution is different...  if you run "grep -rin "user" ." in the directory with the configuration, you might be able to see lines that contain the apache "User" directive... in Ubuntu, the configuration files are actually separated into many files... just try to find the "User" directive...